# How to make a combined header row from n number of list of rows in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How we can do the following steps through Pandas Dataframe.

1. Create a list of the header row, then create another list of the first row and so on.
2. Now join these n number of lists to make a combined column.

Below is my code for the same logic but it is limited up to 3 list.

```
cols1 = list(df.columns)

cols2 = list(df.iloc[0,:])
cols2 = [str(x) for x in cols2]

cols3 = list(df.iloc[1,:])
cols3 = [str(x) for x in cols3]

cols = [x+"__"+y+"__"+z for x,y,z in zip(cols1,cols2,cols3)]

df.columns = cols
```

I want to do for n number of list for n number of rows and then want to add all those as a single row header.

It would be great if any body can help on this.

Comment: you mean `''.join(col1+col2+col3)` ?

Comment: Add some example data so we can visually see what you mean.

Comment: I think this is an X, Y problem and you might be looking for `df.to_dict('split')`. Your rows are `list of lists` into the `data` key, and you have the `columns` and `indexes` available aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us call `n` the number of rows that you want to concatenate to the header. This is enough:

```
cols = df.iloc[:n].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.name + '_' + '_'.join(x))
```

It gives a series indexed by the column names so you can do:

```
df.columns = cols
```

Comment: Thank you Serge for your help. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: next I am doing the below logic to rename and filling NaN values.

Comment: if (r_col == 2):
        for a in range(0, c_col+1):
            df = df.iloc[:,:].rename(columns={'Unnamed: ' + str(a) + '__nan':'Column' + str(a)}).ffill()

    if (r_col == 3):
        for a in range(0, c_col+1):
            df = df.iloc[:,:].rename(columns={'Unnamed: ' + str(a) + '__nan__nan':'Column' + str(a)}).ffill()

Comment: Here r_col is "columns in row header" and c_col is "columns in column header".

Comment: @AbhishekSrivastava: Code in comment is hard to read. In addition, it is now a different question. You'd better ask a new question. If relevant, you can put a link to this one as a context element.

Comment: Hi Serge, Thanks for reply. Please find the above question in this link. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629424/how-to-use-ffill-for-n-number-of-columns-in-column-header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629424/how-to-use-ffill-for-n-number-of-columns-in-column-header)

Comment: @AbhishekSrivastava: BTW, if this answer was useful, you should accept it to inform future readers that you no longer need help on this question.

Comment: I have accepted it, could you please provide your suggestions for the question I asked in this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629424/how-to-use-ffill-for-n-number-of-columns-in-column-header