# How to use ffill() for n number of columns in column header

Tags: python, pandas

Need to fill NaN values from previous row value for n number of columns

I am trying to achieve the below through Pandas Dataframe.

1. Creating lists of rows and joining these to make a combined column in row header.
2. Next I have to use ffill() to fill the NaN values from previous row. For this I'm trying to use if condition based on r_col (columns in row header) and c_col (columns in column header) parameters, but here it is not a best approach as c_col and r_col can be n number of columns and rows.

Below is my code for the same logic.

```
cols = df.iloc[:r_col].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.name + '__' + '__'.join(x))   

df.columns = cols

if (r_col == 2):
    for a in range(0, c_col+1):
        df = df.iloc[:,:].rename(columns={'Unnamed: ' + str(a) + '__nan':'Column' + str(a)}).ffill()

if (r_col == 3):
    for a in range(0, c_col+1):
        df = df.iloc[:,:].rename(columns={'Unnamed: ' + str(a) + '__nan__nan':'Column' + str(a)}).ffill()
```

I need to fill NaN values for n number of columns in Column header means based on c_col parameter and which should be performed after the line "df.column = cols".

Comment: post complete working example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `df[x].fillna(y)` or `df[x].fillna(y, inplace=True)`. Here x is any column of your choice and y is any value of your choice.  For example:

```
1 0.0001
2 NaN
3 0.03
```

gives

```
1 0.0001
2 0.0000
3 0.03
```

or

```py
list_nan_values = [1,2,3, 21, 44]   # variables list to fill NaN with
nan_locations   = [1,2,8,19,67]     # positional location of NaN in specific column you have selected.

for i in range(len(nan_locations)+1):
    df[i] = df[nan_locations[i]].fillna(list_nan_values[i])
```

Enjoy.