# Column arithmetic

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a problem with some code. I have three columns of floating point numbers. I want to add the three columns and then divide by one of the columns.

Thanks

I had the following code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
cols = ['Opening Balance', 'Subscriptions/Redemptions', 'Gain (Loss)'] 
for col in cols:
    df1[col] = pd.to_numeric(df1[col], errors='coerce')
    num = ((df1['Opening Balance'] + df1['Subscriptions/Redemptions'] + df1['Gain (Loss)']))
    denom = df1['Opening Balance']
    performance = num/denom
df['new column'] = performance
```

I end up with a new column that is nothing but NaN.

I was hoping to get a float in return

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Could you please provide a sample dataset that would run with your code?

Comment: check ***> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56630041/8928024) < *** to replace NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to remove the `num` and `denom` parts from the `for` loop. Otherwise they are being overwritten each time. Something more like this:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
cols = ['Opening Balance', 'Subscriptions/Redemptions', 'Gain (Loss)'] 
for col in cols:
    df1[col] = pd.to_numeric(df1[col], errors='coerce')

# escaped for loop here
# also removed parentheses
num = df1['Opening Balance'] + df1['Subscriptions/Redemptions'] + df1['Gain (Loss)']
denom = df1['Opening Balance']
performance = num/denom
df['new column'] = performance
```

Every time you tried to convert one of the column to numeric, it works only for that column. Then when you try to sum the other "non-numeric" columns with it, you'll probably get `NaN` because they haven't been converted yet. Complete the conversions in the loop, then define your `denom` and `num`.

Also, I don't think you need the parentheses around your `num` definition

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly, I appreciate the help

Comment: @gaels67 glad it worked. Please consider marking the answer as correct and upvoting it if possible.