# Eliminating certain keywords from column names in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iterator, multiple-columns

I'm trying to adjust the names of columns in my dataframe and am unsure how to rename each column by iterating through them.

I thought I could make a list of the df columns and then remove the keyword, and then apply that column back to the df as the new column names but wasn't sure how to do that entirely.

For example, if I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     tech 1       tech 2       tech 3
foo    1            3             5
bar    2            3             4
```

How would I remove the "tech" from each column, assuming there are 100+ columns?

Comment: check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56630041/8928024)!.

Comment: Is it as simple as tech 1...n for n columns? If so just `reindex()` to make it numeric. Or rename with a list of the numbers you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("tech", "your_string")
```

This will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Your instinct is correct, you can just use the columns, iterate over with `.replace()` and assign it to the columns attribute

```
df.columns=[i.replace('tech ','') for i in df.columns]
```